# Excel VBA range after filtering xlCellTypeVisible

Tags: vba, excel, filter, range

What I want to accomplish: Open a workbook from a specific address, Filter the first column for value equal to 36 or 541 (I got this first part working), then check column 3 to see if a value of 2 exists and if it exists then filter out everything except for value 2 in column 3; if value 2 does not exist in column 3 then skip.

I tried using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to name the new range but I must be using it incorrectly because it is giving me a value of 2 that exists only in the old range where the data has not been filtered yet.

Thanks for your time!

```
Sub filters()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim nwb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("ADDRESS.FILE.xlsx")

With ActiveSheet

.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("$A$1:$AD$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=36", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=541"
'.Range("$A$1:$AD$5000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2"

End With

Dim newrange As Range

Set newrange = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Integer
intValueToFind = 2
For i = 1 To 5000    ' Revise the 5000 to include all of your values
    If newrange(i, 3).Value = intValueToFind Then
        MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

' This MsgBox will only show if the loop completes with no success
MsgBox ("Value not found in the range!")


End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot use the syntax `newrange(i, 3).Value` to access a value in a multi-area range.

Comment: It still runs even with that syntax. I get the same value even when I put in Cells(i, 3).Value instead of the newrange.

Comment: It will run (ie. it does not throw an error): it just won't give you the correct answer...

Comment: Oh, ok. So I revised it for to say "Cells" instead of "newrange". Is it not possible to check the values in the column after the filter? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim newrange As Range, rw as range

Set newrange = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Dim intValueToFind As Integer
intValueToFind = 2
For Each rw in newrange.Rows
    If rw.cells(3).Value = intValueToFind Then
        MsgBox ("Found value on row " & rw.cells(1).Row)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next rw
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Worked like a charm!